# Changing from Mousehover to Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website uses a vertical menu structure, which operates by Mouseover. Move the mouse over a menu item, the sub-menu shows. Move the mouse away from the menu item, the sub-menu hides.

Due to the fact that there are too many menu items to use the hover function properly without everything going all over the place, I need to change the menu to a click function instead. Similar to this, with a slide function also if possible: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCrk4/17/

I've tried changing the ".hover" to ".click" but that just messes the site up for some reason. Here's the code below:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 "use strict";

 jQuery('#main_menu li').each(function()
 { 
     var jQuerysublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
     
     jQuery(this).hover(function()
     { 
      jQuerysublist.addClass('visible');
     },
     function()
     { 
      jQuerysublist.removeClass('visible');
     });
 
 });

 
 jQuery('#menu_wrapper .nav ul li').each(function()
 {
     var jQuerysublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
     
     jQuery(this).hover(function()
     { 
      jQuerysublist.addClass('visible');
     },
     function()
     { 
      jQuerysublist.removeClass('visible');
     });  
     
 });

...
```

Any help is always appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: use `click` instead of  `hover`

Comment: Thank you dude, however, I have already tried this method, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this, and try it:

```
jQuery('#main_menu li').click(function(){   
    var jQuerysublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');    
    if (jQuerysublist.is('.visible')) {
      jQuerysublist.removeClass('visible');
   } else {
     jQuerysublist.addClass('visible');
   }
});
```

Comment: That's done the trick! Thank you for your input and quick response!

One more thing please, is there a way to close the previous sub-menu when selecting another sub-menu?